# How to use Matches() and Pattern correctly

Tags: java, regex

I'm doing a assignment for school and need to build a Student class. The constructor will receive a String,"Student name". I need to verify that the given String from the user includes only letters from a-z, A-Z, and numbers 0-9.

From looking online this is what I found

```
boolean ans = true;
String str = ("Maor Rocky");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9]\\w+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
System.out.println(matcher.group());

if (!str.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9//s+]"))
    ans = false;

System.out.println(ans);
```

I know it's missing something but I didn't grasp the idea of pattern and matcher yet.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You can use [`[^\W_]+`](https://regex101.com/r/kxvDNV/1) or `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`. See [auto-generated Java code here](https://regex101.com/r/kxvDNV/1/codegen?language=java)

Answer (score 1):

thanks every one, this is the code i wrote and it works:

```
boolean ans = true;
    if (!name.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$")) {
        ans = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have variable student of type String that will hold student name, simple check goes like this (no need to use Pattern or Matcher classes here):

```
String student = scanner.next();
if (student.matches("[\\w]*"))
    //do something for valid username
else
    //do something for invalid username
```

Or do it the same way every beginner would do it:

```
    String student = scanner.next();

    for (int i = 0; i < student.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(student.charAt(i)))
            //do something for invalid username;
    }
```

Comment: `[\w]*` is the same as `\w*`

Answer (score 0):

You need something like that:

```
public class Student {

    private String name;

    public Student(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (!name.matches("[\\w]*")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("name should contain only alphanumeric chars.");
        }
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand the uses of Matcher you should see [This link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html)

In this example the Matcher and Pattern objects aren't doing anything because you are using a String method that works with regexp. If you wanted to use the Matcher your if would look something like this

```
if(matcher.matches())
    ans=false;
```